# Why I cant compute this matrix's argmin?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

my matrix is (20, 20).

when I coded: `type(d)` which is my matrix, it says: `numpy.ndarray`

when I coded: `type(d[1,2])` as an example of an input of it, it says: `numpy.float64`

to add explanation, I was working pytorch and saved the results in a `np.matrix(20,20)`.

I want to find argmin of this matrix and coded: `np.matrix.argmin(d)` which d is my 20*20 matrix.

but got the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-116-0e139e5c160d> in <module>
----> 1 np.matrix.argmin(d)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\matrixlib\defmatrix.py in argmin(self, axis, out)
    755 
    756         """
--> 757         return N.ndarray.argmin(self, axis, out)._align(axis)
    758 
    759     def ptp(self, axis=None, out=None):

AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute '_align'
```

how to find argmin of such matrix?

Comment: don't use `np.matrix`.  Stick with the base `ndarray` class.

Comment: Quoting the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html): "*It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future.*"

Comment: sorry, checked it and I saw I used np.full((20,20), np.inf). the other inforamtion is correct. what should I do?

Comment: `np.matrix.argmin` is an unbound method of the `np.matrix` class. You should almost never call it directly, and you *definitely* shouldn't call it on anything that isn't an instance of `np.matrix`. `np.argmin` is the function you're looking for.

Comment: If `type(d)` is `ndarray` and not `matrix`, then you shouldn't use `matrix` functions on it.

Answer (score 0):

A 2d array:

```
In [167]: A = np.array([[1,3,2],[5,2,1],[3,5,1]])
```

proper ways of using `argmin` - flattened or with an axis:

```
In [168]: A.argmin()
Out[168]: 0    
In [169]: A.argmin(axis=1)
Out[169]: array([0, 2, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Your wrong way of using `argmin`:

```
In [170]: np.matrix.argmin(A, axis=1)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_align'
```

If we first make a `np.matrix`:

```
In [171]: M = np.matrix(A)    
In [172]: M
Out[172]: 
matrix([[1, 3, 2],
        [5, 2, 1],
        [3, 5, 1]])
```

we can use its argmin method:

```
In [173]: M.argmin(1)    # np.matrix.argmin(M, axis=1) also works
Out[173]: 
matrix([[0],
        [2],
        [2]], dtype=int64)
```